# How to create Wifi access point to share internet from wifi connection on the same adapter

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, debian, wireless-access-point

I need to setup the following configuration:
My nettop on Debian needs to connect to external wifi. And at the same time and using the same adapter - create an access point for my phone to be able to connect to it. (On Windows I can do that using Connectify)

It would be great if I can do that using NetworkManager tools.

Answer (score 0):

GAD3R had half the solution to your question. The other half is to 'bridge' the connection between the SSID that allows an internet connection and another 'hotspot' or Access Point as mentioned, and seen, in GAD3R response.

You can bridge the connections in a similar manor using the same command `nmtui`.

ie: `nmtui` >> ***edit a connection*** >> ***add*** >> ***bridge*** >> ***add*** >> ***choose slaves***

[Here's](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/7/html/Networking_Guide/ch-Configure_Network_Bridging.html) an in depth guide with images. When choosing slaves that will be bridged you will need to provide **exact,** SSID's and/or MAC addresses for the network profiles associated with the hotspot and AP with internet. So I recommend writing down the ssid's (case sensitive), passwords, MAC addresses, to avoid confusion and troubleshooting when bridging them.